# best css framework for layouts, boxes, images, ...?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, frameworks

I'm a coder coming from the pre-CSS era and trying to find a powerful but simple CSS framework, that would let me create any kind of layout with boxes I want. 
I already have a wordpress theme so I'm looking for something to include into the theme.
I looked at ez-css which looks nice, but it just seems to do the box layouts, and I was wondering if there exists a framework that comes with many different snippets for typical layout tasks, like a box with a small image + paragraph text, etc. 
I've looked at wordpress themes like pagelines, builder and headway but don't like them very much because they lock me into their themes, and they seem quite fiddly after playing with them. 
Thanks
B

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/

Answer (score 3):

You could have a look at -

blueprint - http://www.blueprintcss.org/

or

960 Grid System - http://960.gs/

Comment: I know about these frameworks, but they seem overcomplicated for what I want to do. I was looking for something like ez-css but with more built in standard layouts.

Answer (score 1):

Have you taken a look at http://960.gs/?

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier for you if you search separately for a CSS Framework and after for a blank WordPress Theme.

Most of these "CSS frameworks" are not really frameworks because CSS is not like JavaScript or PHP, so don't bother spending time with them.

What I will suggest is to get a premium html/css theme and modify it yourself and turn it to your own custom framework.

Comment: I've explored that but these themes don't have lots of layout helpers in them, and are difficult to customize in my experience. If I go with a new theme I have to restyle the whole theme all over again.